# How to modify the slug for the default wp posts without affecting other posttypes?

Tags: permalinks, slug

How can I modify the slug for the default wp posts without affecting other posttypes?

example: `www.example.com/slug-of-post/` should become `www.example.com/blog/slug-of-post/`

I made a few custom post types where I rewrote the slug by using `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),` in the `function.php` file.

Result: `www.example.com/post-type-slug/slug-of-post`

I need the same result but for the default posts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Go to settings -> permalinks -> custom structure

and change that to: `/blog/%postname%/`

But please make sure that in your custom post types definition, (`register_post_type`) set

```
'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),
```

unless the URL of all of your custom post types will be prefixed by /blog/

**UPDATE:**

As @rudtek mentioned in the comment, after your set `'with_front' => false`, you must go to settings->permalinks and hit save again to flush rewrite rules. (This is the solution for many permalink issues)

Comment: I already tried that but it doesnt work..

Comment: It DOES apply /blog to every post, while I did added the code to the other custom post types

Comment: @JeroenKnockaert did you set the with_front key to false for all of your custom post types?

Comment: yes I did. Any other ideas?

Comment: make sure that after you set with_front that you refresh your permalinks (ie go to settings/permalinks and hit save.)

Answer (score 0):

In extension to [pooria's answer above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/258745):

If you are using the CPT UI plugin to manage your custom post types, there is a dropdown to toggle the `with_front` option:

[image: "With Front" option on CPT UI plugin]

By default this option is set to True so you will have to change it for all post types for which you want to start the permalink with your site URL.